# "But, also and interestingly" - Is this properly expressed in English?

Tags: grammar, phrases

**But, also and interestingly**, from an environmental science point of view: in addition, the study of planet atmospheres has not as yet found any evidence of gasses that are "out-of-chemical-equilibrium" such as we observe on earth (with oxygen and methane which are constantly replenished by living organisms).

[Source: The Institution of Environmental Sciences](https://www.the-ies.org/analysis/does-silicon-based-life-exist)

The phrasing "But, also and interestingly" sounds odd to me. I wonder whether "and" should be removed from there.

Comment: The sentence has way too many qualifiers: "but", "also", "interestingly", "in addition"... It's grammatical but it's bad style. In principle it's OK to link adverbs with "and".

Comment: I would have put _and interestingly from an environmental science point of view_ in brackets, or used a dash before and after - and certainly omitted _in addition_.